# Box shadow and border radius not working in Internet Explorer in facebook

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have used box shadow and border radius in my project for facebook application. But in Internet Explorer, it is not working. My css code is given below:

```
.main_body_bg {
     border-radius:2px 2px;
     -moz-border-radius:2px 2px;
     webkit-border-radius:2px 2px;
     background:#f8f8f8;
     width:740px;
     -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(82,82,82,0.5);
     -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(82,82,82,0.5);
     box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(82,82,82,0.5); 
     behavior:url(images/PIE.htc);
 }
```

Anybody can help me?Thanks,Tapas

Answer (score 0):

you need make extra style for IE, written here http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.main_body_bg  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 102px; /* match target width */
    height: 102px; /* match target height */
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='15', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='0.40');
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```